# How to execute tasks with provided timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of tasks like this:

```
const tasks = [
  {
    time: 0,
    consoleLog: "Start",
  },
  {
    time: 3,
    consoleLog: "3 seconds passed",
  },
  {
    time: 4,
    consoleLog: "1 second since last has passed",
  },
  {
    time: 8,
    consoleLog: "Final console log",
  },
];
```

The time indicates in seconds when the task should be run (in this case, `consoleLog` should be console logged.

So, at 0 seconds, `tasks[0]` should run, then at 3 seconds, `task[1]` should run and so on. You can assume that tasks are ordered by time. How can I do this? Some kind of timer?

Comment: Look up setInterval and reduce function

Answer (score 1):

You can use async timeout function and loop.
UPDATE: simplified answer, added inline comments.

```js
// Task list
const tasks = [
  {
    time: 0,
    consoleLog: "Start",
  },
  {
    time: 3,
    consoleLog: "3 seconds passed",
  },
  {
    time: 4,
    consoleLog: "1 second since last has passed",
  },
  {
    time: 8,
    consoleLog: "Final console log after 4 secs from last task and 8 secs from start of loop",
  }
];

// Your mini app
const APP = {
  // App logic
  init: async () => {
    // Init last time variable
    let lastTime = 0;
    // Loop
    for(task of tasks) {
      //
      // Here control timeouts...
      // Calculate current timeout
      const timeout = task.time - lastTime;
      // Wait for timeout to complete
      await APP.timeout(timeout * 1000);
      // Update last time variable
      lastTime = task.time;
      //
      // Here check task type and add it's logic...
      // If console log task
      if(task.consoleLog) {
        // Do console log
        console.log(task.consoleLog);
      }
      // If another task type
      if(task.anotherTask) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  },
  // Timeout function
  timeout: (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
};

// Test
APP.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` and increment a timer - you'd need to ask some other checks to make sure the interval doesn't run forever, but the short of it is:

```
let currentTime = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    let currentTask = tasks.find(t => t.time == currentTime);
    if (currentTask) console.log(currentTask.consoleLog);

    currentTime++;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about executing those tasks once or repeatedly? If you want to execute them only once, you might consider using `setTimeout(callback, delay)`. This will allow you to run the task after the specified delay.

So to execute a single task from your array you'd have to:

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log('Start') }, 3000)
```

For all the tasks in the array, you'll have to iterate over the array and execute the code above like this:

```
tasks.forEach((task) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(task.consoleLog)
  }, task.time * 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
tasks.forEach((task) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(task.consoleLog);
  }, task.time * 1000);
});
```

**NOTE: This is asynchronous**

Comment: `setTimeout` seems to not work inside the for loop?

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't work inside a for loop. Check if there is some problem with your IDE.